# Azure AD permissions and the PUT verb

Tags: asp.net-web-api, azure-active-directory

We have an ASP.Net MVC web site that talks to a WebAPI service. This is authenticated at the application level by using application authentication in Azure AD.

This all works fine for GET and POST operations, but the same tokens don't work for PUT operations, is there any good reason for this?

EDIT - example of how we are calling the service.

We're using an HttpClient to make a call to the WebAPI

```
_httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessToken);
return await _httpClient.PutAsync(url, content);
```

Then we get back a HttpResponseMessage which has status code of Unauthorized.

We're not calling the Graph API directly but using the AAD instance to authenticate the calling of one service by another.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the code (or request) that is failing, along with the response that you get?

Comment: Can you also provide the response you're getting? Is appears as this is your own API that is responding, not AAD.